# Galera cluster slow

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, galera

Why when using a Galera Cluster for mariadb, insertion requests are processed twice as long?

In single mode insert query time ~1.2ms
If turn on cluster query time ~2.5ms

Engine InnoDB and table size > 20Gb

```
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_provider_options="gcache.size=256M"
wsrep_cluster_name="cluster"
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://10.90.1.1,10.90.1.2"
wsrep_sst_method = mariabackup
wsrep_sst_auth = mariabackup:password
wsrep_node_address=10.90.1.1
wsrep_node_name="node1"
wsrep_slave_threads = 8
```

I also have a constant load of about 50 insert requests per second. And if you restart the second node, it is not synchronized until the first one is turned off. How to solve this problem?

Comment: which maria version you are using ?

Comment: # mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.14-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Comment: You only have 2 Nodes ? The minimum ist 3 for a Cluster. When you have only 2 Nodes you cant restart 1. Then there is a split brain.

Comment: One is read only.

Comment: Hard disk drive? or SSD?

Comment: Are the `INSERTs` into the same table?

Comment: I use ssd disk.

Comment: Are the two nodes have same specs(same hardware, same OS)? With proper tuning, you could expect a 10% performance downgrade, otherwise, either not tuning properly or one of them is slowing others down